# Получить SHA комитов, в которых был изменен конкретный файл

Tags: git

Есть ли команда в `git`, которая позволяет отследить, в каких комитах был изменен интересующий файл? Часто для подобных целей пользуюсь утилитой `gitk`, передавая единственным параметром имя файла, но было бы удобнее получить список непосредственно в терминале.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно выдаче гугла на запрос:

> [git get commits for file](https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=git%20get%20commits%20for%20file)

и первой ссылке его выдачи на [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8808453/3212712) вам нужна вот эта команда:

```
git log --follow filename
```

Т.е. например

```
git log --follow c://project/how_to_use_git.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Ещё один вариант:

```
git log -- filename.txt
```

Кстати, так можно указывать несколько файлов:

```
git log -- file1.txt file2.txt
```

Можно отслеживать изменения в папке

```
git log -- path1/ path2/
git log --follow path1/
```

Можно использовать маску, только экранируйте её кавычками, иначе она будет обработана не гитом, а вашей оболочкой командной строки:

```
git log -- '*.txt'
git log --follow '*.txt'
```

Наконец, если вам нужны только SHA коммитов, укажите явным образом формат:

```
git log -- file.txt --format=%H
d84c9aa849128f1efba18a33b9124a803539e697
756f09b93525df5bed436f84058c7245d4e658c2
ff320d1803d9ae2b2e8dc9f9a7349a3f4b2d28a7

git log -- file.txt --format=%h
d84c9aa
756f09b
ff320d1
```